# Outputting an array in alphatabetical order

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if I have the below:

```
var mycars = new Array();
mycars[0] = "Manbearpigs";
mycars[1] = "Cool";
mycars[2] = "Coolz";
mycars[3] = "Radical";
mycars[4] = "GiantCools";
```

What is the best way I could output it in alphabetical order in the HTML.

***Eg:***

Cool
Coolz
GiantCools
Manbearpigs

Comment: Are you using any data binding framework like KnockoutJS or AngularJS or at least using jQuery? That would make your life easier when trying to display Javascript data in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Sort it

```
var mycars = new Array();
mycars[0] = "Manbearpigs";
mycars[1] = "Cool";
mycars[2] = "Coolz";
mycars[3] = "Radical";
mycars[4] = "GiantCools";
mycars.sort();
```

[**Array Sort**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: @downveter did i missed something.

Comment: I thought it was a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sort method 
so your code would be mycars.sort();

Answer (score 1):

Use can use array.sort() method to sort your array:

```
mycars.sort();
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Underscore Library](http://underscorejs.org/), which the best one for operating data in JavaScript